# Efficient way of creating WPF view elements on demand by VM flag

Tags: c#, wpf

Usually my view elements are created by the standard method of binding a `ControlControl.Content` to a property that contains a VM or null. This is nice because WPF will only create the view element (via an implicit `DataTemplate`) if the VM actually exists.

I have another chunk of UI that has its visibility toggled via a VM flag. Normally I would use a boolToVisibilityConverter for this. However, this chunk of UI is reasonably expensive to create, and rarely appears.

Instead I only want to go to the expense of view construction if the flag is toggled on. I came up with the following:

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeVMFlag}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <vw:ExpensiveView/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

This feels pretty clunky, and I can't help feeling there's a better way? Any suggestions?

Comment: What prevents you from using the same approach (exposing the view-model only when `SomeVMFlag` changes) for that view?

Comment: There is no separate VM for this UI chunk. It uses the same VM as its container.

Comment: You could still expose it by a property like `public SomeVM SomeVM { get { return SomeVMFlag ? this : null; }}`. Of course with property change notification.

Comment: True! I'd have redeclare the new view template at some point which makes it slightly messier, but might give that one a try and see how it feels. Thanks both.

Comment: Depending on the MVVM framework you use this can be already available. Diffrerent ViewModels map to different Views, so when you bind a ViewModel to the ContentControl the corresponding View will be loaded based on the *type* of the VM

Comment: You can use the [ContentTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) of your ContentControl to select a template based on your own logic. You can create your own [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=netframework-4.7.2) to implement this logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per dynamoid and Clemens suggestion. I have implemented a separate dummy VM property that just returns the parent VM when the flag is set.

View is then simply:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding DummyExpensiveVM}">
    <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <vw:ExpensiveView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Much cleaner, many thanks both.

**EDIT**: Nope! This does **NOT** work since the template is a literal and gets constructed regardless of content. I suspect the same is true of my original implementation too.

Instead the template must be an implicit template defined in the view resources just like you'd normally do for MVVM.